# 'Rear Camera' and 'Flash light' Not Working in Lenovo k6 Note (Custom Rom)

Tags: custom-roms, camera, camera-flash

I am not able to use Rear Camera and Flash Light in My Lenovo K6 Note. Front Camera Works Well.
When I open Camera App, by default it Opens with Front Camera. Rear Camera Option is Not Found. (Front Camera works Perfectly Fine)

Even when i opened WhatsApp and Take a pic, only front camera is shown. No Button to switch To Rear Camera. (Front Camera works Perfectly Fine)

When i swipe Down the status Bar and try to switch on 'Flash Torch light'. it is not working.

In Stock Rom, Front and Rear Camera Works Fine even Flash Light Works Fine.

**Solutions Tried**

- https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=71423852&postcount=112 Tried But Not Working (Both Solution not Working)
- Download libmmcamera2_sensor_modules.so from my github, override /system/vendor/lib/libmmcamera2_sensor_modules.so in your phone, take care file permission, then reboot your phone. Even This Is not Working
- Used Rom lineage-14.1-20180319-UNOFFICIAL-karate . Not working
- Used Validus_Karate.zip still not working same Problem As above

**Device:**

Device : Lenovo K6 Note

Android Version : 7.1.2

Os : lineage-14.1-20180319-UNOFFICIAL-karate (Flashed Using TWRP)

Rooted : Yes

**Just a Doubt**

I downloaded 'karate' and there is a rom with name 'karateP' . I have a no idea what is it, Im a noob. Am i facing problem because of this ? I am Not sure.!

Comment: As this is an unofficial build: have you checked with its corresponding forum thread whether those are known issues? Also see: [Recommendation for questions pertaining to a problem specific to a nightly build of a ROM](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/16575), as "unofficial builds" (with issues like that) often fall into that context. // BTW: The XDA link in your question does not work.

Comment: You probably need to port your stock firmwares camera libs and lib64's along with the stock camera application... Usually some files from system/firmware as well

Comment: @Zillinium and lzzy thanks for suggestions..!



I got the solution..! I flashed a wrong ROM. it should be karatep, so i flashed karatep, now everything works great.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/k6-power/development/rom-lineageos-15-0-lenovo-k6-power-t3685009


K6/Power (karate). 
K6 Note/Plus (karatep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u need to flash the rom named Karatep. the one you flashed in for k6 power. 
K6 Power(Karate)
K6 Note (Karatep)

https://forum.xda-developers.com/k6-power/development/stable-unofficial-lineageos-lenovo-vibe-t3635064

Comment: Thanks, you are right.